# using a jQuery UI Slider value in a separate slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've put together a rates calculator so bands can work out how much a rehearsal costs each (price for total of hours / band members = cost per band member) and I've got it working to a point.  When the slider for #members is moved it needs to recalculate based on the value of getCost, based on the #hours value.  I know it is set below to only show the price per member based on the value of #hours and not the value of getCost, but anything else I do breaks the #hours slider.  How do I get it to recalculate based on the getCost value?

http://jsfiddle.net/4YYWd/6/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#hours" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value:1,
        min: 1,
        max: 7,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#paraOne").text(getCost(ui.value));
            $('#paraTotal').text('£' + (getCost(ui.value) / ($('#members').slider("value")).toFixed(2)));
            $('#prhours').text(ui.value);
        }
    });

    $("#members").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 6,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#paraTwo").text(ui.value);
            $('#paraTotal').text('£' + (($('#hours').slider("value") / ui.value).toFixed(2)));
        }
    });
});


function getCost(nRate){
    var costToReturn;

    switch(nRate){
        case 1:
            costToReturn = 10;
            break;
        case 2:
            costToReturn = 20;
            break;
        case 3:
            costToReturn = 28;
            break;
        case 4:
            costToReturn = 36;
            break;
        case 5:
            costToReturn = 44;
            break;
        case 6:
            costToReturn = 52;
            break;
        case 7:
            costToReturn = 60;
            break;
    }

    return costToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight change to your code it works:

```
(...)
$('#paraTotal').text('£' + (getCost($('#hours').slider("value")) / ui.value).toFixed(2));
(...)
```

See [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YYWd/9/).